Get Shared calendar Microsoft Graph API via /me/calendars
I've created an application in which I need to access a shared calendar. To do so, I use the GET /me/calendars endpoint.
Sometimes I see the shared calendar. When this isn't the case, if I add this calendar to my Outlook mobile application, the problem is solved normally. But sometimes, even if I add the shared calendar to my mobile app, it still doesn't show up in the GET /me/calendars endpoint.
Does anyone know why?
